# Usages of std::move

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Below in the question is a simplified version of code for SO. The original code:

- Receives a structure that should not be modified or invalidated
- Creates a different structure that has some data copied from the original structure
- The newly created structure is intended to not be modifiable, all members are `const`
- The newly created structure cannot have a constructor that knows about the original structure

The simplified code for SO doesn't have the original structure, I just made up data with loops. However the detail which is still important is that the new structure's constructor will be passed `std::vector`. Those are populated in the loops and moved to the new structure

It occurred to me that the `std::vector` will not be needed after the new structure is made so `std::move` would be appropriate. I have labeled the usages as "Move 1", "Move 2", "Move 3", and "Move 4" in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    const int m_a;

    A() = delete;
    A(const int a_a) : m_a(a_a) {}

    void display() const { std::cout << "    " << m_a << "\n"; }
};

struct B {
    const std::vector<A> m_as;
    const int            m_b;

    B() = delete;
    B(
        std::vector<A>&& a_as,
        const int        a_b
    ) :
        m_as(std::move(a_as)), // Move 1
        m_b(a_b)
    {}

    void display() const {
        std::cout << "  " << m_b << ":\n";
        for (const A& a : m_as)
            a.display();
    }
};

struct C {
    const std::vector<B> m_bs1;
    const std::vector<B> m_bs2;

    C() = delete;
    C(
        std::vector<B>&& a_bs1,
        std::vector<B>&& a_bs2
    ) :
        m_bs1(std::move(a_bs1)), // Move 2
        m_bs2(std::move(a_bs2))  // Move 2
    {}

    void display() const {
        std::cout << "0:\n";
        for (const B& b : m_bs1)
            b.display();
        std::cout << "1:\n";
        for (const B& b : m_bs2)
            b.display();
    }
};

int main() {
    // Manually making up data, actual usage will take data from a different
    // kind of structure and populate vectors
    std::vector<B> bs1, bs2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::vector<A> as;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
            as.emplace_back(j);
        bs1.emplace_back(std::move(as), i); // Move 3
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::vector<A> as;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
            as.emplace_back(j);
        bs2.emplace_back(std::move(as), i); // Move 3
    }

    C c(std::move(bs1), std::move(bs2)); // Move 4
    c.display();
    return 0;
}
```

**Some assumptions**:

- I believe that there is no significant difference between "Move 1" and "Move 2"
- I believe that there is no significant difference between "Move 3" and "Move 4"
- To the best of my knowledge `std::forward` is not a good replacement for any of the `std::move` usages because there are no templates

**The question**:
Are all of the `std::move` usages meaningful or are any of them unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, the moves make sense. No you shouldn't replace them with std::forward. As an additional note: reserve capacity in your vectors before filling them up with your loops to avoid reallocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see most of the `std::move`s are required by removing them, your code wont compile. The only exceptions are `Move 1` and `Move 2`, the code will still compile without them but only because the `std::vector` copy constructor is invoked instead.

If you want to move from an object you almost always need to use `std::move`, the only exceptions are when moving from a temporary and when returning an object.